# How to use one cycle for different tags

Tags: xslt, foreach

I have XML with different same tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
  <ROUTES>
    <A1_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1021</A1_NE>
    <A2_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1022</A2_NE>
    <Z1_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1023</Z1_NE>
    <Z2_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1024</Z2_NE>
  </ROUTES>
  <ROUTES>
    <A1_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1001</A1_NE>
    <A2_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1002</A2_NE>
    <A3_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1003</A3_NE>
    <A4_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1004</A4_NE>
    <Z1_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1005</Z1_NE>
    <Z2_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1006</Z2_NE>
   </ROUTES>
</main>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <MAIN>
        <xsl:for-each select="main/ROUTES"> 
            <xsl:element name="ROUTES">
                <A_NE><xsl:value-of select="A1_NE"/></A_NE>
                <A_NE><xsl:value-of select="A2_NE"/></A_NE>
                <A_NE><xsl:value-of select="A3_NE"/></A_NE>
                <A_NE><xsl:value-of select="A4_NE"/></A_NE>
                <Z_NE><xsl:value-of select="Z1_NE"/></Z_NE>
<Z_NE><xsl:value-of select="Z2_NE"/></Z_NE>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each> 
</MAIN>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How I can use for-each command to transform A1_NE, A2_NE etc to A_NE column?
And also I've not understand how I can know number of the row in the source xml.

Perhabs xslt version 1.0 couldn't do this transformation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
<ROUTES>
<A_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1021</A_NE>
<A_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1022</A_NE>
<Z_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1023</Z_NE>
<Z_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1024</Z_NE>
<A_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1001</A_NE>
<A_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1002</A_NE>
<A_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1003</A_NE>
<A_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1004</A_NE>
<Z_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1005</Z_NE>
<Z_NE>LSN/EMS_XDM_12/1006</Z_NE>
</ROUTES>
</main>
```

Comment: Your output XML seems to be exactly the same as you input? I suspect that is not what you want! Can you also say what version of XSLT 2.0 you are using (as this may be a grouping problem, and that is handled differently in XSLT 2.0). Thanks!

Comment: I use xslt 1.0 I'm trying to create "for each" cycle for different tags. For instance in source file I have A1_NE tag and A2_NE tag. Those values i will insert in the one column NE in the one table.

Comment: You should really edit your question to show the output you expect. Also, if you had tried some XSLT already, you should include that in your question too. Thank you!

Comment: I corrected body of the question. In the source there are some tags: <A1_NE>, <A2_NE> e.t.c it could be more that two. I need transform this values to the one column <A_NE>

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of template matching, to change the node names.

First select the child nodes of all `ROUTES` like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="main/ROUTES/*" />
```

Then, have templates like this, for example, to do the renaming

```
<xsl:template match="A1_NE|A2_NE|A3_NE|A4_NE">
  <A_NE><xsl:value-of select="."/></A_NE>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <main>
      <ROUTES>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="main/ROUTES/*" /> 
      </ROUTES>
    </main>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="A1_NE|A2_NE|A3_NE|A4_NE">
    <A_NE><xsl:value-of select="."/></A_NE>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Z1_NE|Z2_NE|Z3_NE|Z4_NE">
    <Z_NE><xsl:value-of select="."/></Z_NE>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, if those are indeed your real element names, you could try and make it generic

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <main>
      <ROUTES>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="main/ROUTES/*" /> 
      </ROUTES>
    </main>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="ROUTES/*">
    <xsl:element name="{substring(local-name(), 1, 1)}_{substring-after(local-name(), '_')}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic that needs to be applied is not apparent from the example given. Perhaps all you need to do is:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/main">
    <main>
        <ROUTES>
            <xsl:for-each select="ROUTES/*"> 
                <xsl:element name="{translate(name(), '1234567890', '')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>     
       </ROUTES>
    </main>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```